# How to JOIN two joined subqueries for a total of a five-table JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two queries, each of which works perfectly and gives me the results I desire.

Query 1:

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID, s.ID) ID, 
    COALESCE(m.Test, r.Test) Test, 
    COALESCE(m.School, r.School, s.School) School, 
        m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3,  
        r.E_Col1, r.E_Col2, r.E_Col3, 
        s.First, s.Last 
    FROM Tabl1 AS m 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS r 
    ON(m.Test = r.Test AND m.ID = r.ID) 
INNER JOIN Table3 AS s 
    ON COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID)= s.ID
```

This gives me:

```
ID   TEST       M_Col1  M_Col2  M_Col3  E_Col1  E_Col2  E_Col3  First  Last
101  2013-MEG3   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   John  Smith
102  2013-MG3    Stuff   Stuff   Stuff                           Jane  Doe
102  2013-EG3                            Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Jane  Doe
103  2013-MG5    Stuff   Stuff   Stuff                           Joe   Smithe
103  2013-EG5                            Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Joe   Smithe
104  2013-MEG6   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Jane  Dawn
105  2013-MG6    Stuff   Stuff   Stuff                           Jaime Swans
106  2013-EG6                            Stuff   Stuff   Stuff   Jaime Swans
```

My Second Query, Query 2:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Test, t.Other, t.Other_No 
   FROM Table4 as t
FULL OUTER JOIN Table5 as a
   ON (a.Other_Key = t.Other_Key)
```

This gives me a similar table result.

What I want to do is JOIN these two subqueries together, basically:

```
(
  SELECT
    COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID, a.ID) ID, 
    COALESCE(m.Test, r.Test, a.Test) Test, 
    COALESCE(m.School, r.School, s.School) School, 
        m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3,  
        r.E_Col1, r.E_Col2, r.E_Col3, 
        s.First, s.Last 
FROM
  Tabl1 AS m 
FULL OUTER JOIN
  Table2 AS r 
    ON(m.Test = r.Test AND m.ID = r.ID) 
INNER JOIN
  Table3 AS s 
    ON COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID)= s.ID
)
  q1

FULL OUTER JOIN

(
  SELECT
    a.ID, a.Test, t.Other, t.Other_No 
  FROM
    Table4 as t
  FULL OUTER JOIN
    Table5 as a
      ON (a.Other_Key = t.Other_Key)
)
  q2
    ON(q1.ID = q2.ID)
```

But this doesn't work. It just gives me the results of Query1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you reformat your queries to use indentations, etc (as I've done for your final query) it's much easier to see what's going on.  The first thing I notice is that it doesn't start with `SELECT ... FROM`.  Is that a typo?  Or is that the cause of your problems?  *(Also, as a strong principle, if you want us to debug problem code, it helps us A LOT to actually give us the error message you get.)*

Comment: Another problem is that you first query tries to read from alias `a`, but you don't have a table or view aliased to `a` in that query.  So, Query1 can't possibly have run?  *(I think you probably meant `s`)*

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. If you give an image, include a legend/key/explanation. Insert images/links using edit functions.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You don't explain or give an example of what you want. How are we to know? PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe assuming a lot here, but I think this may be close to what you want:

```
SELECT COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID, s.ID, q2.ID) ID, --added ID from query 2 to coalesce function
    COALESCE(m.Test, r.Test, s.Test, q2.Test) Test, --added Test from query 2 to coalesce function
    COALESCE(m.School, r.School, s.School) School, 
    m.M_Col1, m.M_Col2, m.M_Col3,  
    r.E_Col1, r.E_Col2, r.E_Col3, 
    s.First, 
    s.Last 
    --add q2.Other or q2.Other_No here if you want to return from query 2
FROM Tabl1 AS m 
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 AS r 
    ON(m.Test = r.Test AND m.ID = r.ID) 
INNER JOIN Table3 AS s 
    ON COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID)= s.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT b.ID, b.Test, t.Other, t.Other_No 
    FROM Table4 as t
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table5 as a
    ON (a.Other_Key = t.Other_Key)
) q2 ON COALESCE(m.ID, r.ID, s.ID) = q2.ID
```

Comment: This works, except that it gives a bunch of rows where everything is NULL except for what's `q2.Other` and `q2.Other_No`. Would that be fixed with a simple `LEFT JOIN` instead of `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Yes - a full outer join will return every row from every table involved, regardless of whether there is a match. That's why you see so many NULLs. If you wanted to change those to inner joins, you could also probably get rid of your COALESCE functions, since you won't have to look through a bunch of nulls before you find a value.

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions, comment for clarification & vote down & flag/vote to close.